# How do I copy player data from one account to another in the same bedrock world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing with a friend in a bedrock edition world. My friend created a Microsoft account to use, but this caused him to respawn in the world with nothing. Using MCC Tool Chest, I attempted to copy the player data from his old account to his new one, but was unable to figure it out. I got as far as figuring out which player needed to be copied to which, but didn't find a "copy player button". When selecting the original player, I found I was only able to clone one file at a time.

So, to summon things up, I found I can slowly copy files from one player to another, but I am asking for a better method. Any suggestions are welcomed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you just swap his new Id in the old character?

Comment: @DelsaranBigglesworth How would I do this? I tried renaming the "package" but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was trying to ask you before the moderator deleted my response, and since I don't 50 rep (Which is stupid) couldn't answer the question. You should be able to click on the top level tag like "Inventory" in this picture and then click the button at the top of the screen, circled in red. Then find your friends new character and paste this copied tag in with the paste button\located to the right of the copy. Hopefully this saves you some time move each individual item.

[image: Copy the top level]

Try this program instead. You can copy the whole player folder and paste it.

[image]

https://www.universalminecrafteditor.com/

Comment: Would this copy all the stats? Like XP levels, respawn position, and pets? My understanding is that you need to transfer each file for the player separately, as selecting everything results in the copy button being grayed out.

Comment: The Universal Minecraft Editor program worked well! I will always use it from now on.